# How two combine multiple reads in fasta file?

Tags: r, unix, fasta

I want to merge multiple sequences into one:
What I have:

> ENST00000361624_ORF.1 273-306 type:complete length:33 frame:1 start:ATG stop:TGA

ATGGCGTTTCCCCGCATAAACAACATAAGCTTC

> ENST00000361624_ORF.2 828-861 type:complete length:33 frame:1 start:ATG stop:TGA

ATGATATCAATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTATCGTG

> ENST00000361624_ORF.3 1305-1347 type:complete length:42 frame:1 start:ATG stop:TGA

ATGCCCCGACGTTACTCGGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCACA

> ENST00000361899_ORF.2 168-201 type:complete length:33 frame:1 start:ATG stop:TGA

ATGATAACCATACACAACACTAAAGGACGAACC

> ENST00000361899_ORF.3 510-678 type:complete length:168 frame:1 start:ATG stop:TAA

ATGCACCTAATTGGAAGCGCCACCCTAGCAATATCAACCATTAACCTTCCCTCTACACTTAT
CATCTTCACAATTCTAATTCTACTGACTATCCTAGAAATCGCTGTCGCCTTAATCCAAGCCT
ACGTTTTCACACTTCTAGTAAGCCTCTACCTGCACGACAACACA

> ENST00000361899_ORF.4 140-188 type:complete length:48 frame:3 start:ATG stop:TAA

ATGACTAATCAAACTAACCTCAAAACAAATGATAACCATACACAACAC

What I want:

> ENST00000361624

ATGGCGTTTCCCCGCATAAACAACATAAGCTTCATATCAATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTATCGTGCCCCGACGTTACTCGGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCACA

> ENST00000361899

ATGATAACCATACACAACACTAAAGGACGAACCCACCTAATTGGAAGCGCCACCCTAGCAATATCAACCATTAACCTTCCCTCTACACTTATCATCTTCACAATTCTAATTCTACTGACTATCCTAGAAATCGCTGTCGCCTTAATCCAAGCCTACGTTTTCACACTTCTAGTAAGCCTCTACCTGCACGACAACACAACTAATCAAACTAACCTCAAAACAAATGATAACCATACACAACAC

Since my dataset is kind large, I am unable to merge these manually. I just wondering if anyone have any experience with that and could provide some possible way to handle this question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that a file or data already in R?

Comment: "In unix" do you mean the system Unix or a program?

Comment: what type/name of database are you storing in? And Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
require( tidyverse )
require( Biostrings )

# ENST00000361624_ORF.1 .2 ,and .3
u <- c(
    'ATGGCGTTTCCCCGCATAAACAACATAAGCTTC'
  , 'ATGATATCAATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTATCGTG'
  , 'ATGCCCCGACGTTACTCGGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCACA'
)

# What I want:ENST00000361624
U <- 'ATGGCGTTTCCCCGCATAAACAACATAAGCTTCATATCAATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTATCGTGCCCCGACGTTACTCGGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCACA'

# Where do each of the pieces appear in the desired result?
seq( u ) %>% map( ~str_locate_all( U, u[ . ] )) %>% unlist( recursive = FALSE )

# [[1]]
#      start end
# [1,]     1  33          <---- Part 1 matches precisely at the beginning
# 
# [[2]]
#      start end          <---- Part 2 doesn't match, at least not without some edits
# 
# [[3]]
#      start end          <---- Part 3 doesn't match, at least not without some edits
```

```
num_chunks <- length( u )
chunk_lengths <- map_int( seq( u ), ~nchar( u[ . ] ))

num_chunks
# [1] 3

chunk_lengths
# [1] 33 33 42

num_bases_in_chunks  <- map_int( seq( u ), ~nchar( u[ . ] )) %>% sum

num_bases_in_wanted <- nchar( U )

num_bases_in_wanted
# [1] 102

num_bases_in_chunks
# [1] 108

num_extra_bases <- num_bases_in_chunks - num_bases_in_wanted
num_extra_bases
# [1] 6

## What you have and what you want
# have: 3 chunks, total of 108 bases
# want: 1 chunk , total of 102 bases

# How do you know which order to combine parts .1, .2, and .3?
# How do you know that there are extra bases?
# How do you know which bases to remove?
```

## Combining is easy -- Getting the result you want may be harder

### Getting from here to there

```
# Manually translating { ENST00000361624_ORF.1 .2 ,and .3 } to  { What I want:ENST00000361624 }

# ENST00000361624_ORF.1 matches precisely with the first 33 bases of { What I want:ENST00000361624 }
# ATGGCGTTTCCCCGCATAAACAACATAAGCTTC     # u[ 1 ]          start:ATG stop:TGA
# ATGGCGTTTCCCCGCATAAACAACATAAGCTTC     # from head

# ATG ATATCAATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTATCG TG   # u[ 2 ]        start:ATG stop:TGA
#     ATATCAATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTATCG      # from middle

# The final 32 bases of ENST00000361624_ORF.3 match precisely with the final 32 bases of { What I want:ENST00000361624 }
# ...AATTGGCTTCCTAGGGTTTA TCGTGCCCCGACGTTACTCGGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCACA   # to tail
                        A    TGCCCCGACGTTACTCGGACTACCCCGATGCATACACCACA   # u[ 3 ]        start:ATG stop:TGA
```

The `Biostrings` Package provides memory efficient string containers, string matching algorithms, and other utilities, for fast manipulation of large biological sequences or sets of sequences. This will probably be useful for what you are trying to do. Note that installation can be a bit complicated, particularly for those of us not deep into BioConductor.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# install.packages('Biostrings')
# Warning message:
# package ‘Biostrings’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2) 

# install.packages("BiocManager")
# BiocManager::install(version = "3.12")
# BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
# require( 'Biostrings' )
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Two functions, in particular, you might find useful are `compareStrings` and `gregexpr2`.

`compareStrings` combines two equal-length strings that are assumed to be aligned into a single character string containing that replaces mismatches with "?", insertions with "+", and deletions with "-".

```
string1 <- "ACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATC---AAAGG---AAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAG"
string2 <- "GTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATC"

compareStrings( string1, string2 )
# [1] "??TTCAC?A??TCC?T???GGTAAGT??AT?---AAA??---AAA???A?A?TTTTCA??"
```

`gregexpr2` is a replacement for the standard gregexpr function that does exact matching only. Standard gregexpr() misses matches when they are overlapping. The gregexpr2 function finds all matches but it only works in "fixed" mode i.e. for exact matching (regular expressions are not supported).

Thank you for the interesting question! I hope this helps.